# htaccess issue after setup restriction to folders

Tags: file, .htaccess, directory

I have a demand where I need to deny access to a folder (localhost\uploads\video). I got this by applying the below rule in the htacess at localhost:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(|avi|mp4)$ - [F,NC]
```

Scenario 1 - It works fine if I try to access the resoruce (.avi files mainly)by typing the address straighforward in the browser and this is the message:
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /video/23/videoname.html on this server. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**THIS IS OK**.

Scenario 2 - With tis rule applied, if I try to click in any link in my homepage which leads me to the video I'm also getting the same message than in scenario 1 and this isn't what I wanted to. I thought when I would access through homepage(by clicking over the avi link) this message wouldn't come.

How can I get this done in this way? I want to block over direct access but I want to keep it working fine if this be executed from homepage...

Regards
Eliel

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be problem for URI pattern matching. Change you rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www\.)?domain\. [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(avi|mp4)$ - [F,NC]
```

Make sure to replace `domain` with your actual domain name.

Comment: Are you getting forbidden for non avi/mp4 files also?

Comment: This is the original website by the way: www.pererecapedia.com
This is what I have now: 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?pererecapedia/ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?pererecapedia.*$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule \.(|avi|mp4)$ - [F,NC]

I'm wondering whether I can accomplish that... In the page itself there exists a flashplayer which goes to the page through a javescript insert...
Regards

Comment: That means you didn't even take my suggested rule. How can it work then?

Comment: Hi anubhava, I took your suggestion, as well see:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www\.)?pererecapedia\. [NC] 
    RewriteRule \.(avi|mp4)$ - [F,NC]
Due the limitation for writing I didn't mention that version as well :(

Comment: You need to replace your rule with m suggested rule. If you keep your rule you will keep getting error.

Comment: Hi anubhava it is working I tested in another folder (other for which no rewrite rule is defined) and that is working fine. However it isn't working for the folder I wanted to and now I understood why, I will explain you in details: I'm applying this rule under domain/videos/ folder and after this declaration you advised me, there exists another rewrite rule which is overwriting your suggestion: 
      RewriteRule ^video/(.*)/(.*) playvideo.php?videoid=$1&page=$2. 
This is making the request (even when by url) been as not REFERER and that is why it isn't working.

Comment: Oh ok in that case you should post your current rules by editing your question so that I can give you better suggestion.

Comment: tis page playvideo.php has a setence:
   STemplate::display('playvideo.tpl');

This is automatically including the content and that means REFERER won't be detected.

Any ideia what could I do for overcoming this?

Comment: I have no idea how `STemplate::display` works but let me know what URL server gets then I can think of something.

Comment: this is the url www.pererecapedia.com and for testing purpuse you can try to access this video (this video won't play bu for testing you will see that anyway you are able to access it) http://www.pererecapedia.com/video/48/drop6.html.

In fact you can try access any video from home if you want.

Just for your information: the video folder is under another folder in the server. So folder structure is: 

pererecapedia\uploads\video

Right now the rule is applied:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www\.)?pererecapedia\. [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(avi|mp4)$ - [F,NC]

Comment: Just for testing purprose try to access http://www.pererecapedia.com/js/48.avi

You will see the forbiden message and rule working fine....